# tinymce default applied (written) style

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I'm using tinymce to edit some field in a web application.
I need to have an html result (after editing) with some specification.

For example: when I press enter tinymce create a new paragraph (that's ok, and I know this behaviour can be changed, but paragraph is ok).

What I need is a specific style to the paragraph be applied.
I saw there is the possibility to specify content_css, but this is a visual deformation of what is written in the edited html.

my need is when I press enter a paragraph with specific style (margin, alignmnent, ..) must be written directly in the edited html text.

e.g. `<P style="margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:10px"> ...</P>`

Is it possibile to define specific style to be applied to each html tags ?

I need this because after editing, the html content is used in another part of application, where I can not add additional style configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try that?

```
...
'content_css' : './path/to/your/styles.css',
...
```

*styles.css*

```
p {
   margin-top:2px;
   margin-bottom:10px
}
```

**..I saw there is the possibility to specify content_css, but this is a visual deformation..**

True, but don't forget that this visual deformation is extracted when you call `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()`.
Though, i'm not sure it will extract your specific styles applied to `<p>` (untested)

Check also [here](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=26294)

**UPDATED**

Ok, i have another suggestion using HTML parsing using [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
$html = str_get_html("<div>add here your HTML from tinymce editor <p></p></div> test <p></p>");
foreach($html->find("p") as $p) {
   $p->style = "margin:2px 0 10px 0";
}
$html_modified = $html;
```

The `$html_modified` should contain the `<p>` with margin applied.

Comment: I tried content_css, and it work visually, but as I wrote in the question, I need the style configuration directly in the code of the 'hidden' text area, when i store the data.

I copy the data with ed.getContent(), and inspectioning the editor html i can see "p{ margin: 0} but looking at the written html there is only <p> xyz </p> without any margin conf.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in tinymce. Just go to **Tools -> Source Code** of the editor toolbar. Write your HTML code with style there. You can try yourself.

Comment: I need different style automatically applied (to paragraph, to span..), i can't ask to the final user to fix the style manually in the html source code editor :)

Comment: Then see this one http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:importcss_file_filter